# return rows for given employees even if data does not exists in sql developer

Tags: sql, oracle

My sql query returns proper result for given employees for a particular week

for eg. my employee list is (emp1 , emp2 , emp3 , emp4)

IF emp4 has not done any work for that week , row for that employee is not returned at all .

My query is as follows :

```
select a.creator_login ,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'NCE- Installation' then a.duration else 0 end) as NCE_Installation ,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'NCE- Migration' then a.duration else 0 end) as NCE_Migration ,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Circuit Testing' then a.duration else 0 end) as NCE_Circuit_Testing ,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Communication - External' then a.duration else 0 end) as NCE_Communication_External,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Communication - Internal' then a.duration else 0 end) as NCE_Communication_Internal,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'Exception' then a.duration else 0 end) as Exception,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Configuration' then a.duration else 0 end) as NCE_Configuration,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Design Reqt Gathering' then a.duration else 0 end) as NCE_Design_Reqt_Gathering,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Documentation' then a.duration else 0 end) as NCE_Documentation,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'Notes' then a.duration else 0 end) as Notes,
sum (case when b.openingcode = 'GOC Acceptance' then a.duration else 0 end) as  GOC_Acceptance,
sum (case when a.activitytype = 'To Do' then a.duration else 0 end) as To_Do 
from vware.snap_ticketactivities a , vware.snap_troubletickets b 
where a.ticketrowid  = b.ticketrowid  
and a.creator_login in ('AMITTAL','HSHARMA','NKHAN','PKSINGH','PPATNANA','PTHAKUR','SDAS','SPATEL','VDASS','VVIGNESHWARAN','AOAK') and a.created between  trunc(sysdate-12)  and trunc(sysdate-6 )
group by a.creator_login
```

If the employee record for the week does not exist still the employee name should be displayed with 0 values

Comment: You should delete [old version of your question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20852701/have-a-entry-in-sql-with-0-if-the-record-does-not-exists-for-that-period) to avoid duplicates.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin Hey can u please help me \

Comment: If you have separate table where employee names are stored then you could outer join it to your tables in query. `emp4` should be in that table and it will be in resulting query.

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin , I know it can be done if there is another table with the employee names , but how can i do this in my case , Check my query

Comment: How do you know that mentioned employee exists at all? There should be information about him somewhere. Where do you get the list for `IN` clause?

Comment: @YaroslavShabalin i have a requirement to fetch data only for these employees , All these employees are there in the database working from time to time , If an employee has not worked in a week , his data wont show . All employees are there in database

Comment: You need to use a left join instead (and stop using implicit joins in the where clause)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
select emp_list.creator_login,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'NCE- Installation' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as NCE_Installation,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'NCE- Migration' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as NCE_Migration,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Circuit Testing' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as NCE_Circuit_Testing,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Communication - External' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as NCE_Communication_External,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Communication - Internal' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as NCE_Communication_Internal,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'Exception' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as Exception,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Configuration' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as NCE_Configuration,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Design Reqt Gathering' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as NCE_Design_Reqt_Gathering,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'NCE-Documentation' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as NCE_Documentation,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'Notes' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as Notes,
       sum(case
             when b.openingcode = 'GOC Acceptance' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as GOC_Acceptance,
       sum(case
             when a.activitytype = 'To Do' then
              a.duration
             else
              0
           end) as To_Do
  from (select 'AMITTAL' creator_login
          from dual
        union all
        select 'HSHARMA'
          from dual
        union all
        select 'NKHAN'
          from dual
        union all
        select 'PKSINGH'
          from dual
        union all
        select 'PPATNANA'
          from dual
        union all
        select 'PTHAKUR'
          from dual
        union all
        select 'SDAS'
          from dual
        union all
        select 'SPATEL'
          from dual
        union all
        select 'VDASS'
          from dual
        union all
        select 'VVIGNESHWARAN'
          from dual
        union all
        select 'AOAK' from dual) emp_list
  left outer join vware.snap_ticketactivities a on emp_list.creator_login =
                                                   a.creator_login
 inner join vware.snap_troubletickets b on a.ticketrowid = b.ticketrowid
 where nvl(a.created, trunc(sysdate - 12)) between trunc(sysdate - 12) and
       trunc(sysdate - 6)
 group by emp_list.creator_login;
```